# Glitched output in second monitor using Nouveau with Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

For some reason my second monitor output is glitched like this:
[image: this]

It works fine with Windows 10 and, for whatever reason, seems to work when the password prompt for my encrypted drive is shown.

Configuration:

- Laptop `Asus FX705DY`
- CPU `R7 3750H`
- GPU `NVIDIA GTX 1650 mobile`.
- The monitor is connected through the HDMI port.
- `Ubuntu 20.04.01LTS, kernel 5.4.0-49 generic`.

I have tried switching to a few versions of the proprietary NVIDIA driver, namely version 435, 440, and 450, but doing so makes the system unanble to recognize the second monitor. The output of xrandr in those cases do not include the second monitor.

Comment: How do you connect those monitors, one by HDMI and another via USB-C dongle?.

Comment: @CarlesMateo I use my laptop's built-in monitor and connect the second monitor via a HDMI cable.

Comment: What is the resolution and refresh rate you're requesting to the monitor?. Monitors don't support all the resolutions/frequencies. You can see in Settings > Devices > Displays.

Comment: @CarlesMateo It doesn't work with the native res and refresh rate at 1920x1080 75Hz. I tried other resolutions and refresh rates as well, none of them work either. If you want to double check then the model of the monitor is LG LG 24MK430h.

Comment: Can you check if you have FreeSync enabled in the monitor?

Comment: Also make sure that the cable is HDMI (D-SUB doesn't support 75Hz) and that is a decent one. If it was supplied with the monitor is fine, but if was yours, make sure is good enough. It could be a cable problem. Also try to display 1920x1080 at 60Hz instead of the 75Hz.

Comment: @CarlesMateo I used the stock HDMI cable that came with the monitor. And as I said in the post, it works fine with windows 10. And I'm not using anykind of converter.